# Show UIAlertView at some interval in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsdate, uialertview

I am developing iPhone app in which i got stuck at one point,

What i want to do is,

When user launches the app for the first time **in a day**, i want to show him a some alert. And when he opens a app for the second time in same day it will not get an alert. (he will get an alert only for the first launch of app in day).

next day again if he opens the app for the first time again he will get alert and on second time he will not get an alert.

**In short: User should get alert on first launch of each day.**

**Any idea, how should i achieve this ?**
***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: See this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions)

Answer (score 1):

I have usefull category to `NSDate` that includes the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)isOnTheSameDayAs:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    return ((components1.year == components2.year) &&
            (components1.month == components2.month) &&
            (components1.day == components2.day));
}

- (BOOL)isToday
{
    return [self isOnTheSameDayAs:[NSDate date]];
}
```

That do most necessary things. Later in app delegate I would place field `NSDate * lastReloadDate` which I would initialize with "day zero". The last action:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (![self.lastLoadDate isToday]) {
        // Show error here and don't forget to hide previous alert view or use singleton for UIALertView.
        self.lastLoadDate = [NSDate date];
    }
}
- (NSDate *)lastLoadDate {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDate *d = [defaults objectForKey:@"LastReload"];
    return d == nil ? [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0] : d;
}

- (void)setLastLoadDate:(NSDate *)d {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:d forKey:@"LastReload"];
}
```

Comment: What is `lastLoadDate` ?

Comment: Sorry I added implementation for `lastLoadDate`.

Comment: I am getting error in `applicationDidBecomeActive` in this line `if (![self.lastLoadDate isToday]) {`

Comment: As I said I am using custom NSDate category with `- (BOOL)isToday` and `- (BOOL)isOnTheSameDayAs:(NSDate *)date` methods. Milo added link to this repo in the comment.

Comment: I have added that two files which Milo has given but still same error facing.

Comment: And you did add #import "NSDate+Utilities.h" to the file you are using it?

Comment: You forgot to add @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * lastReloadDate; You can live without it by calling getter directly.

Comment: Dude i added my alert in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and wrote your code snippet but alert gets called on each launch

Comment: God sake. I have written it from the beggining. Here: http://pastie.org/9415065 you got all code from AppDelegate. IT WORKS. Don't kill application immidietly, bul use cmd+shift+H and kill it like a normal app. If not call [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize].

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to test whether the app is opened for the first time in a day or not. if you are able to do this than to show the alert only once for the day is very easy

```
//Check for new day
if (condition) {

    //For every new day you will clear the user default value
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AlertShownToday"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}

//Below code will check wether the alert is shown for the day or not and accordingly will show alert
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"AlertShownToday"] boolValue]) {
    //Show Alert

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    //Save in userdefault that alert has been shown
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"AlertShownToday"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Use the above code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

When user launches the application, you can store the `currentDate` in the `NSUserDefaults`. Now whenever user launches the application, compare the `currentDate` with the `storedDate` in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
if (currentDate != [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastDate"]) {
    currentDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[NSDate date]];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Day Changed" message:@"Welcome Back!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Hope this helps!!!